# Bind Exclude not working Model Binding for child objects in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, custom-model-binder

I got into a issue in Model Binding in Asp.Net MVC. I have view model like below,

```
public class ArticleViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {        
        public Article art { get; set; }
        public List<ArticleAttachment> attachments { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to exclude model binding a property on the "Article" child object as seen below in my action method,

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult New([Bind(Exclude = "art.Abstract")]ArticleViewModel articleVM)
 {
```

But the model binder populates the property called Abstract even with the above setting.

Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong. I need to exclude some of the properties in the Article child object when doing Model binding.

Comment: See this :- 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341917/asp-net-mvc-3-model-binding-and-form-fields

Comment: Thanks! i tried setting prefix but no luck

Comment: Try [Bind(Exclude = "Abstract")

Comment: Thanks Rick! tried [Bind(Exclude = "Abstract")] but did not work..