# Bind Exclude not working for child objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the same problem as this question and tried the suggested solutions but no luck.. Any help will be very appreciated.
[Bind Exclude not working Model Binding for child objects in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587893/bind-exclude-not-working-model-binding-for-child-objects-in-asp-net-mvc)

The problem is as following:
I got into a issue in Model Binding in Asp.Net MVC. I have view model like below,

```
public class ArticleViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {        
        public Article art { get; set; }
        public List<ArticleAttachment> attachments { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to exclude model binding a property on the "Article" child object as seen below in my action method,

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult New([Bind(Exclude = "art.Abstract")]ArticleViewModel articleVM)
 {
```

But the model binder populates the property called Abstract even with the above setting.

Comment: How can we possibly tell what wrong with your code if you don't show it!

Comment: It is the same code in the question link in my question :)

Comment: You need to include the code in your question, not a link (what happens if that question gets deleted!)

Comment: The question was updated :)

Answer (score 1):

To make this work, you need to apply the `[Bind]` attribute the `ArticleAttachment` class.

```
[Bind(Exclude="Abstract")]
public class ArticleAttachment
{
  public string Abstract { get; set; }
  ....
}
```

However, any time you use either the `[Bind(Include="..")]` or `[Bind(Exclude="..")]` attributes, delete them and do it properly using a view model to represent what you want to edit.