# How should I pass values through to a validation action in a Controller if my values are linked to variables of an instance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I have only just started using MVC and jQuery validate so please bear with me. I also have no idea what the title of my question should be. 8(

**Overview**

I am using MVC 4 with jQuery validate. My form is being validated on the client side. I have a scenario where two very alike objects need to be on my form. This has been achieved by means of a ModelView which has two properties. The ModelView is linked to the View and everything works excepting the remote validation. I need to validate a field based on a particular value in the object. Everything is linked together nicely excepting the parameters of the validation action in the controller. *Before you give me disapproving* tsk tsks,  *I made up the following code scenario.*

**The Code**

**Model** class where `Name` requires remote validation depending on the value of `GroupID`. Essentially, the name is unique to the group.

```
public class Colour
{
    [Key]
    public int GroupID {get;set;}

    [Required]
    [Remote("ColourExists", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "GroupID")]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

**Validation** controller where the `ColourExists` action resides.

```
public class ValidationController :Controller {
    public JsonResult ColourExists(string name, string groupID) {
        // Add validation here later
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

The **View** and **Controller** is linked to a **ModelView** so that I can display two separate instances on my form. Typically I need to ask the user for a Bright and a Dark colour for one group. (*Before you tsk, remember, this isn't for real*)

```
 public class ColourViewModel {
     public Models.Colour BrightColour { get; set; }
     public Models.Colour DarkColour {get;set;}
 }
```

The **generated HTML** has input fields `BrightColour_Name` and `DarkColour_Name`. These fields have `data-val-remote-additionalfields=*.Name` attributes. On blur they `GET` the correct action and controller but the parameters are null. The expected parameters are `InstanceName.VariableName` such as `BrightColour.Name` and `DarkColour.Name`. The request is sent as follows `Validation/ColourExists?BrightColour.Name=red&BrightColour.GroupID=10`

So how should I pass the values through to the `ColourExists` action in the validation Controller if my values are linked to variables of an instance?

***Edit***

The view looks as follows:

```
@model Colours.ViewModels.ColourViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DarkColour.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DarkColour.Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DarkColour.GroupID)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Comment: Can you try pass a single parameter of type `Colour` into your `ColourExists` method? Just a wild guess but maybe MVC is smart enough to serialize the query params into an object...

Comment: I did a straight `get` request to the controller with `name` and `groupID` and it worked. The moment it is Colour.Name and Colour.GroupID the variables are `null`. I also tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317523/how-to-use-bind-prefix but couldn't get it to work :(

Comment: So I managed to get the values via `HttpContext.Request.Params["DarkColour.Name"]`. Is there anything wrong with that method that I may not be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, in this situation you would use a prefix in your remote validation action like here:

```
public JsonResult ColourExists([Bind(Prefix = "BrightColour")] string name) {
    // Add validation here later
    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

But, you can't do that in your case, because you are using two same entities in your ViewModel (not ModelView), and each has its own Prefix. So, the binding fails.

So, you'll have to create two separate ViewModels:

```
public class BrightColourViewModel
{
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Remote("BrightColourExists", "Home", AdditionalFields = "GroupID")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DarkColourViewModel 
{
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Remote("DarkColourExists", "Home", AdditionalFields = "GroupID")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then, redefine your ColourViewModel like here:

```
public class ColourViewModel
{
    public BrightColourViewModel BrightColour { get; set; }
    public DarkColourViewModel DarkColour { get; set; }
}
```

And, then create two separate remote validation actions like this:

```
public JsonResult BrightColourExists(BrightColourViewModel brightColour)
{
    // Call shared code to check if colour exists
    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public JsonResult DarkColourExists(DarkColourViewModel darkColour)
{
    // Call shared code to check if colour exists
    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Do you have to do something special to get the Bind attribute to work? If I add it there and access the controller directly the argument is always null.

Comment: I'll need to see your View. Can you post it here?

Comment: I never had a view for my ValidationController. The ValidationController returns a JsonResult. I couldn't get the Bind attribute to work with the controller on its own.

Comment: "The generated HTML has input fields BrightColour_Name and DarkColour_Name". That's the View I'm referring to. I need to see the View that generates that html page.

Comment: I bypassed the view and accessed the controller directly thus taking the view out of the picture entirely and accessed the controller through the browser http://localhost/validation/colourexists. I will update the question with the sample view code.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do that. But, if you try the following, the Bind attribute will probably work:
`localhost/validation/ColourExists?BrightColour.Name=LightBlue`

However, as I said before, you can't use the Bind attribute in your case, because you have two identical entities in your ViewModel. So, you'll have to create two separate ViewModels (like in  the answer above), one for BrightColour and one for DarkColour, and create two separate validation actions for each.

Comment: I understand that and have found a work around. I just wanted to get the Bind attribute to work because I have never used it before but for some reason could not get it working. I resorted to using the QueryString parameters. The Bind attribute returned null regardless. Thanks for all your help though.