# Is it possible to have a generic [Bind] in c# methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

what I try to do is to bind every incomming value from my response to a string or stringlist dynamicly / generic.

So assume I would know each POST-Value of my request, e.g.

```
string1 = Test
string2 = Test2
```

I would write:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoFoo(string string1, string string2)
{
}
```

or

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoFoo(string string1, [Bind(Prefix = "string2")string myString2)
{
}
```

My situation know is, that I have X strings with my post request. So I dont know the exact number nor the names to catch in my backend.
How to catch every given Post-value without knowing this / how to catch the values dynamicly?

Comment: How about a dictionary? How about you directly use `Request.QueryString["string2"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't feel that why you have to use `Prefix` with `BIND`, when you have to bind every incoming field of response. Bind is not a good choice for that. You can use bind if you have multiple entities at the same time. [Reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317523/how-to-use-bind-prefix)

> that I have X strings with my post request.

If you have to use all the fields then you can use `FormCollection` or `Model` object to receive those fields. FormCollection automatically receive all the fields from view and bind them to a collection. See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/710776/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-An-Absol) for proper example. And a code snippet is below for reference.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {   
        Student student = new Student();

        student.FirstName = collection["FirstName"];
        student.LastName = collection["LastName"];
        DateTime suppliedDate;
        DateTime.TryParse(collection["DOB"], out suppliedDate);
        student.DOB = suppliedDate;
        student.FathersName = collection["FathersName"];
        student.MothersName = collection["MothersName"];

        studentsList.Add(student);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

However if you have to deal with only one particular field/set of fields then you can use either `Include` or `Exclude` as per your convenience with `BIND`. Example shown [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) and code snipped is added below.

In following way you are telling that you only want to include "`FirstName`" of User model while receiving the form content. Everything else will be discarded.

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Edit([Bind(Include = "FirstName")] User user)
{
    // ...
}
```

And in following example you are telling that, please exclude "`IsAdmin`" field while receiving the fields. In this case, value of `IsAdmin` will be `NULL`, irrespective of any data entered/modified by end-user in view. However, in this way, except `IsAdmin`, data rest of the fields will be available with `user` object.

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Edit([Bind(Exclude = "IsAdmin")] User user)
{
    // ...
}
```