# ASP.NET Core CheckBox always returns false value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Does anyone know why I'm always getting a false value when I update the form? I tried with (value="false") into the checkbox but still doesn't work. Any help is appreciated!

```
<form asp-controller="Weather" asp-action="Update" method="POST">
    <tr>
        <td>@city.City</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="cityId" value="@city.Id" hidden/></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" asp-for="@city.OnHeader" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" asp-for="@city.OnProfile" /></td>
        <td><a asp-controller="Weather" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-cityId="@city.Id"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt color"></i></a></td>
        <td><button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-edit color"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Update(WeatherModel theWeather, int cityId)
{
    _weatherService.Update(cityId, theWeather.OnHeader, theWeather.OnProfile);
    return RedirectToAction("Settings");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WeatherController`'s `Update` API expects that will receive `theWeather` and `cityId` parameters. The expected receive data is as below:

```
{
  "theWeather": {
    "onHeader": `<boolean value>`,
    "onProfile": `<boolean value>`
  },
  "cityId": `<numeric value>`
}
```

While you submit the form for `Update`, you are sending data to API as below:

```
{
  "city": {
    "onHeader": `<boolean value>`,
    "onProfile": `<boolean value>`
  },
  "cityId": `<numeric value>`
}
```

Hence, `theWeather.onHeader` and `theWeather.onProfile` will get the default `boolean` value (`false`) as `theWeather` value is not received from front-end.

---

### Solutions

**Solution 1: Apply `name` attribute for `<input>` elements aimed for model binding**

- Will submit the form with data includes `theWeather` object to API.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="theWeather.OnHeader" asp-for="@city.OnHeader" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="theWeather.OnProfile" asp-for="@city.OnProfile" /></td>
```

---

**Solution 2: Rename `Update` `theWeather` parameter to `city`**

- Ensure that the `city`  parameter is matched with the HTML form.

```cs
public IActionResult Update(WeatherModel city, int cityId)
{
    _weatherService.Update(cityId, city.OnHeader, city.OnProfile);
    return RedirectToAction("Settings");
}
```

---

**Solution 3: Use `[Bind(Prefix = "city")]` attribute**

- Model binding will looking through the sources for the key `city` instead of `theWeather`.

```cs
public IActionResult Update(([Bind(Prefix = "city")] WeatherModel theWeather, int cityId)
```

---

### References

[Custom Prefix - Model binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-prefix)

[How to use Bind Prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317523/how-to-use-bind-prefix)